# Script is stuck saying 1 response with 2 available: Math related

Tags: bash, scripting, math

I have a script that tells the user the square footage of 2 rooms based on user input. I think I have that part done right. The problem I have is that I need to have the script say which room is bigger and no matter how I try to rebuild the end of the script I get both responses, 1 of the responses which is wrong unless the user is lucky, or I get no response. How do I change this part of the script to get the correct output? I'll have the rest of the script as a reply to this for those that want to skip over the working part along with the question I've been given. Also this is a homework assignment from my Intro to Unix class that I've spent way to much time on trying to figure out so the correction has to be somewhat beginner-ish.

```
    if [ $R1z -ge $R2z]
    then
    echo Room 1 is bigger
    else
    echo Room 2 is bigger
    fi
```

All of the code:

```
    echo Enter the length of room 1
    read R1x
    echo Enter the width of room 1
    read R1y
    echo Enter the length of room 1
    read R2x
    echo Enter the width of room 2
    read R2y
    expr $R1x \* $R1y
    read R1z
    expr $R2x \* $R2y
    read R2z

    if [ $R1z -ge $R2z]
    then
    echo Room 1 is bigger
    else
    echo Room 2 is bigger
    fi
```

Comment: Question from assignment: Write a script that will evaluate the square footage of two rooms and tell which room is larger. The user will provide you with the dimensions of the first room and the dimensions of the second room.

Comment: The `if then` snippet you posted should work fine - only one branch should ever execute.  Are you sure you pasted it exactly as is?

Comment: @jw013 
Thank you for your reply. Yes that's exactly how I have it in the script.

Comment: Kudos to you for clearly mentioning that this is homework and posting how you actually tried to solve it!

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your script as you pasted it:

```
expr $R2x \*$ R2y
```

should read

```
expr $R2x \* $R2y
```

You should also put the following at the top:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to make sure it is executed with the right shell.
Your `expr` does not do anything useful, certainly the results are not read back into R1z or R2z. What you probably want to do is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter the length of room 1
read R1x
echo Enter the width of room 1
read R1y
echo Enter the length of room 1
read R2x
echo Enter the width of room 2
read R2y
R1z=$(expr $R1x \* $R1y)
R2z=$(expr $R2x \* $R2y)

if [ $R1z -ge $R2z ]
then
echo Room 1 is bigger
else
echo Room 2 is bigger
fi
```

Comment: I made those changes. I'm still getting the same response as before, after making the syntax changes.

Comment: @user52710 I updated my answer with the full working code, somehow my text about your (mis)use of `expr` went missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contained a couple of typos. Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter the length of room 1
read R1x
echo Enter the width of room 1
read R1y
echo Enter the length of room 2
read R2x
echo Enter the width of room 2
read R2y
expr $R1x \* $R1y
read R1z
expr $R2x \* $R2y
read R2z

if [ $R1z -ge $R2z ];
then
echo Room 1 is bigger
else
echo Room 2 is bigger
fi
```

Specifically this line needs to be like this:

```
if [ $R1z -ge $R2z ];
```

#### Example runs

**Room 1:** 1L x 2W, **Room 2:** 3L x 4W

```
$ ./cmd.bash 
Enter the length of room 1
1
Enter the width of room 1
2
Enter the length of room 2
3
Enter the width of room 2
4
2
2 
12
12
Room 2 is bigger
```

**Room 1:** 4L x 3W, **Room 2:** 2L x 1W

```
$ ./cmd.bash
Enter the length of room 1
4
Enter the width of room 1
3
Enter the length of room 2
2
Enter the width of room 2
1
12
12
2
2
Room 1 is bigger
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes on your code (and hopefully the answer):

- Instead of `echo`ing a prompt for the user each time, you can use `read`'s `-p` switch:

  ```
  read -p 'Enter the length of Room 1' R1x
  ```
- `]` does indeed need to be separated by a space from `$R1z` or `$R2z` (it must be the last argument to `[`). The only way the code you posted would work is if `$R1z` and `$R2z` have trailing whitespace.
- I don't get why you need to `read R1z`, it should be the result of `expr`, no? I think this is what's causing the problem. Instead, you want something like `$()` to capture the output of `expr` into `R1z` and do away with the `read` altogether:

  ```
  R1z="$(expr $R1x \* $R1y)"
  R2z="$(expr $R2x \* $R2y)"
  if [ ... ]
  ```